# How to pass a pytest function a browser to open to perform the test's actions in

Tags: python, selenium, web-applications, automated-tests, pytest

I am trying to write test code for a web application in python using pytest and selenium.
My code looks like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pytest
import time

def test_OpenBE(browser):
    browser.get('urlremoved.com')

def test_navigateToSubmit(browser):
        browser.get('urlremoved.com')
        time.sleep(10)
        browser.find_element_by_id('button').click()

def test_Submission(browser):
        browser.get('urlremoved.com')
        browser.find_element_by_id('Name').send_keys("Name here")
        browser.find_element_by_id("ID").send_keys("123456")
        browser.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("email@email.com")
```

I have found examples where passing the browser in this way worked. However, when I tried to run it using pytest, I recieved the error:

fixture 'browser' not found

> ```
>   available fixtures: cache, capfd, capsys, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_xml_property, recwarn, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>   use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.
> ```

Does anyone know how to implement this so that the tests can run as intended?

EDIT: I downloaded chromedriver and set a variable

```
driver= webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe')
```

This seems to have done something to make progress ubt now I am getting an error:

ValueError: Plugin already registered: pytest_webdriver=)>

Answer (score 4):

You can initialize browser before calling it, for example.

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Or you make a fixture yourself by defining the function ideally in a file called `conftest.py`. You can read more on the pytest website. Here's an example:

```
@pytest.yield_fixture(scope='session')
def browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

pytest is looking for `browser` fixture. Probably you don't have this fixture declared. you can read about fixtures here -> https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html.

and you can use pytest-selenium plugin http://pytest-selenium.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

however, you can try to implement something like this in the same file...

```
@pytest.fixture
def browser():
    "pytest fixture for browser"
     return pytest.config.getoption("-B")
```

Comment: Do you know of a pytest fixture for browser? I haven't been able to find one in that list or through google

Comment: You can just make your own fixture for browser?  Maybe this would be helpful for other people also?

Comment: I'm very inexperienced with test code development and webdriver/selenium. I would write my own fixture if I knew how but right now I'm just trying to make sure my approach to writing the test script works? I may look into it if I can't find a solution though!

Answer (score 0):

Clarification for anyone who stumbles upon this when trying to figure our where to get a browser fixture for Playwright.  The browser fixture is made available by pytest-playwright (https://pypi.org/project/pytest-playwright/). You probably don't need to go down a selenium/chromium rabbit hole to initialise it.